# Typescript local file class 'Cannot find module'

Tags: node.js, typescript

Having the below folder structure

```
- api
  - routes
    - meeting.ts
- models
  - DynamoService.ts
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

DynamoService.ts

```
export class DynamoService {
...
}
```

meeting.ts

```
import { DynamoService } from 'models/DynamoService'

const dynamoService = new DynamoService()

// other Express stuff...
```

When testing this I receive the below runtime error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'models/DynamoService'
```

Before trying to move the functionality into a class module having some DynamoDB helper methods in `meeting.ts` was working just fine.
Visual Studio Code doesn't complain about anything, no compile errors.

That should be a simple task but I seem to have trouble!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this problem.

### Relative reference

You could simply change the import line like this:

```js
import { DynamoService } from '../../models/DynamoService'
```

### Typescript path alias

Another convenient way is to leverage this nice TypeScript feature by configuring `paths` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
        "models/*": ["models/*"]
    },
}
```

See more in https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths or https://medium.com/slackernoon/use-typescript-aliases-to-clean-up-your-import-statements-7210b7ec2af1.

Comment: Thanks, none of the above worked...so annoying. I don't have any 'src' as baseUrl.

Comment: Deleting the .build folder set in outDir, adding '../../' did the trick, supposedly setting the baseUrl to './' should have worked but doesn't look like that. Trying paths at the moment doesn't help as well, sticking to using dots until I understand why. Thanks!

Comment: that's weird, but glad to hear that you have overcomed this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Super weird and tried with couple of projects following documentation etc...obviously doing something Typescript newbie mistake